# how to make two-step animation progressbar by using css animation?

Tags: html, css

I want to make two-step progress bar animation: the red bar run to the middle and its color is turned to yellow, then another yellow bar will appear in the middle and runs to the end.

I tried to add "display: none" in class progressbar2 but it will disappear in the beginning. How can I do to make yellow bar (class:progressbar2) appear after 2 seconds and it doesn't appear in the beginning?

[Here is codepen code](https://codepen.io/lovelearning/pen/rQXVPa)

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.progress1 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: becomeyellow 2s linear;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
}

.progress2 {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: becomegreen 2s 2s linear;
}

@keyframes becomeyellow {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}

@keyframes becomegreen {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: none;
  }
  100% {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="progress1"></div>
  <div class="progress2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: there no `display: none` property in your css?

Comment: I tried to add display: none in progress2 but whole yellow bar disappear in the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added **opacity:0** in the  **progress2** class at the last line.

And on the animation **becomegreen** I added **opacity:1** when you're setting 100% of the animation.

And that worked very well.